# Whitespace in textarea

Tags: php, textarea, whitespace, simple-html-dom

I build an array of URLs from the content of a textarea, than process it with simple php dom.

I get this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.example.com )
```

Obviously, there is a whitespace at the end of the URL (which is the last in the array and the last in the textarea)

I checked other questions on stackoverflow, but I still can not get rid of this whitespace and get my script to work, even though my textarea tag contains no whitespaces at all.

This is what my textarea looks like (no whitespace anywhere):

```
    <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" value=""></textarea><br><br>
```

The array is separated by `\n`

I even make sure to delete possible whitespaces using the `del` key after the last entry in the textarea, but I keep getting the same error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using the trim() function to get rid of extra whitespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function will do what you need it to. Just change your `file_get_contents($url)` to `file_get_contents(trim($url))` and it should never have that problem.

Comment: awesome! that worked. Any idea why that is though? After all I don't have whitespace in my html.

Comment: Without seeing the exact code you're using to get the contents of the text area, as well as any processing between that and the file_get_contents call, it's hard to tell.

Sometimes things like this can be a browser being strange and other times it can be your code. Either way, doing a `trim` in this case sounds like a good call anyway, in case a user were to accidentally put spaces before or after their entries.